# Double integral with a variable in limits

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I am trying to solve this integral:
[image]

This is what I tried:

```
NIntegrate[(x*
exp[-859.69 (1 - (x/5.5949)^0.7288)^1.4428])*(exp[(-723.3)*
 NIntegrate[
  exp[-859.69 (1 - (y/5.5949)^0.7288)^1.4428], {y, 0, x}]]), {x, 0, 0.01}]
```

But I get the error that
"The integrand exp[-859.692\ (1- 0.285108 x^0.7288)^1.4428] has 
evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the 
region with boundaries {{0,0.01}}."

I also tried:

```
f[x_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[exp[-859.69 (1 - (y/5.5949)^0.7288)^1.4428], {y, 0, x}]
NIntegrate[(x*
exp[-859.69 (1 - (x/5.5949)^0.7288)^1.4428])*(exp[(-723.3)*
 f[x]]), {x, 0, 0.01}]
```

This doesn't work as well.
Can you please help?

Comment: It would help if you changed exp for Exp. Doing that, I get 0 as an answer in both approaches.

Comment: All that is not from real life in view of `Maximize[{Rationalize[Exp[-859.69 (1 - (y/5.5949)^0.7288)^1.4428], 
    10^-20], y >= 0 && y <= 1/100}, y];N[%, 20]` which results in`{9.6459631058223982615*10^-369, {y -> 0.010000000000000000000}}`.

Answer (score 0):

NIntegrate is smart and tries to analytically analyze the integral before numerical calculations. You may see this by:

```
Clear[f]
f[x_] = (Print[x]; x)
NIntegrate[f[x], {x, 0, 1}]
(* x *)
```

This prints `x` and then the result and not as expected some numbers between 0 and 1. Therefore, your inner integral is called with a symbolic `x` and you get an error message. You can prevent this by specifying:

```
Clear[f]
f[x_?NumericQ] = (Print[x]; x)
NIntegrate[f[x], {x, 0, 1}]

(*1, 0.00795732,...*)
```

Therefore, what you need to do is to define the inner integral as a function with `NumericQ`. Further as the result is zero, you need to specify an accuracy.

```
Clear[f]
f[x_?NumericQ] := 
  Exp[(-723.3)*
    NIntegrate[
     Exp[-859.69 (1 - (y/5.5949)^0.7288)^1.4428], {y, 0, x}]];
NIntegrate[(x*Exp[-859.69 (1 - (x/5.5949)^0.7288)^1.4428])*f[x], {x, 
  0, 0.01}, AccuracyGoal -> 6]
```

Comment: All that is not from real life in view of `Maximize[{Rationalize[Exp[-859.69 (1 - (y/5.5949)^0.7288)^1.4428], 
    10^-20], y >= 0 && y <= 1/100}, y];N[%, 20]` which results in `{9.6459631058223982615*10^-369, {y -> 0.010000000000000000000}}`.